# Picard group of $M_{g,n}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

It is well known that the Picard group of $M_g$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by the Hodge bundle. What is the Picard group of $M_{g,n}$, the moduli space of curves with marked points?

Comment: See the paper "The Picard groups of the moduli spaces of curves", Topology 26, 1987, by Arbarello and Cornalba.

Comment: @ulrich: This is an answer, not a comment.